# Ansible: [WARNING]: Found both group and host with same name

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Using the `ec2.py` inventory script to query against my EC2 instances. I keep getting the following warning signs. How can i suppress them by fixing what's causing the issue?

```
[WARNING]: Found both group and host with same name: nex-1.XYZ.net
[WARNING]: Found both group and host with same name: admin-1.XYZ.net
[WARNING]: Found both group and host with same name: jenkinsmaster-1.XYZ.net
```

Comment: More here on this feature here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/22519

Answer (score 18):

Spotting the reuse of the same name as host and group is easy :

```
[webserver]
webserver
```

But it might be trickier because sometimes it's just you have forgotten to add the `:children` in your group definition

This definition will rise a Warning :

```
[webservers]               # <-- 'webservers' is a group
web1
web2

[agent_x]
webservers                 # <-- 'webservers' is a host
```

While this one won't :

```
[webservers]               # <-- 'webservers' is a group
web1
web2

[agent_x:children]
webservers                 # <-- 'webservers' is a group
```

Quote from ansible 2.4 documentation https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.4/docs/docsite/rst/intro_inventory.rst#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables

> It is also possible to make groups of groups using the :children suffix in INI or the children: entry in YAML

Meaning you have to be explicit whether the group will list `hosts` or `groups`.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because you probably have the same names into your inventory, for example this follow inventory:

```
[webserver]
webserver
webserver1
```

We have one host called webserver and the same name into group, could be a problem when you want to do something to group webserver don't you think?

If it happens when you use Dynamic Inventory like ec2.py the name probably is duplicated into your AWS envinronment, I recommend you change this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem in a very simple way: i forgot to add **:children** after my groupname